# C - qsort sends the wrong pointers to the comparator function?

Tags: c, debugging, qsort

My problem is that qsort seems to be sending weird pointers to the comparator function. The comparator function itself seems to be working fine if I create 2 gaps and send their pointers as arguements. However, when debugging I'm getting wrong values, even though the gap array is initialized correctly.

I am running the code on Windows 10 if that matters.

Gap definition and comparator function:

```
typedef struct open_space_t{
    ssize_t size;
    off_t start;
}Gap;

int GapComparator(const void * aa, const void * bb){
    ssize_t a = ((Gap*) aa)->size;
    ssize_t b = ((Gap*) bb)->size;

    if(a>b){
        return 1;
    }
    if(b>a){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Running qsort:

```
Gap** allGaps = malloc((2) * sizeof(*allGaps));
allGaps[0] = malloc(sizeof(*allGaps[0]));
allGaps[0]->size = 20;
allGaps[0]->start = 30044;
allGaps[1] = malloc(sizeof(*allGaps[0]));
allGaps[1]->size = 20;
allGaps[1]->start = 30064;
qsort(allGaps, 2, sizeof(*allGaps), GapComparator);
```

Comment: @melpomene I see, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparator receives pointers to the elements it should compare. Your array elements are pointers (`Gap *`). Therefore the comparator receives `Gap **`.

Fix:

```
int GapComparator(const void * aa, const void * bb){
    ssize_t a = (*(Gap**) aa)->size;
    ssize_t b = (*(Gap**) bb)->size;
```

Or alternatively:

```
int GapComparator(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const Gap **pa = aa, **pb = bb;
    ssize_t a = (*pa)->size;
    ssize_t b = (*pb)->size;
```